# Remove closest dropdowns and validate dropdowns in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

What I presently have is this code which goes on appending new dropdowns when the add.png image is clicked upon.
**And what I need is to remove dropdowns one by one upon clicking on the remove.png image**.

```
<tr>
  <td valign="top">Order</td>
  <td colspan="3">
     <div id="salesPersonList">
        <select name="sales[]" id="sales" class="sales" style="margin-bottom:1px;">
           <option></option>
           <?php 
              require_once '../model/sales.php';
              @$result2=Sales::getAllSalesPerson();
              while($value2=mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
           ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $value2['id']; ?>">
              <?php echo $value2['name'] ?>
           </option>
           <?php } ?>
        </select>
     <span class="salesPersonEr" style="display:none;color:red;margin-left:30px;">Select the Sales Person Order</span>
     <img src="../../common/images/add.png" width="20" height="20" name="add" value="Add" onclick="addSalesPerson()" style="margin-left:323px;margin-top:-23px;"/>
     <img src="../../common/images/remove.png" width="18" height="18" name="del" id="del" value="del" onclick="removeSalesPerson()"/>
     </div>
  </td>
```

The Script:-

```
function addSalesPerson(){
    var salesPersonListt=$('#sales').html();
    $('#salesPersonList').append("<select name='sales[]' id='sales' class='sales' style='margin-bottom:1px'>"+salesPersonListt+"</select>");
}

function removeSalesPerson(){
     //Please Help
}
```

The appending part is perfect and it works. What I need is the removal portion.
**And** the other segment that I need is when I click on the submit button(#submit) the form must be validated such that there should not be a dropdown option that is:-

1. Empty(That is without an option value selected).
2. A particular dropdown option should not be equal to another dropdown option. (E.g.:- SalesPerson id of 3-Mark in the first appended dropdown and the fifth appended dropdown also hold a SalesPerson id of 3-Mark)

Any help is very much appreciated!!!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You're appending elements with same `id`, which is invalid... You should remove the `id` from the `HTMLString`. Also, please aviod using inline styles: [Why use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS). BTW, You've better chances of getting help if you strip out the `PHP` and post the generated `HTML` instead... also, the shared code does not contain the form or submit button... the less code you post, less accurate answers you get...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether there are more than one matching elements using the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property of jQuery object and remove the element using [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove) method:

```
function removeSalesPerson(){
 if($('#salesPersonList select').length > 1) 
   $('#salesPersonList select:last').remove();
}
```

For the validation, you can use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) method for preventing the normal form submission process and submit the form later manually, if validation success using `submit()` method:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault(); // prevent normal  form submission
 var failure = false,
 emptySelects = $("#salesPersonList select").filter(function(){ // loops through all selects
    return !this.value; // returns empty selects
 });
 if(emptySelects.length) // if there are empty selects, simply return.
   return;
 else{
  // loop through each select and compare it's value with the rest of selects
  $("#salesPersonList select").each(function(){ 
     var val = this.value, // store the value of current select
     matches = $("#salesPersonList select").not(this).filter(function(){ // loops through rest of the selects
          return this.value == val; // return selects whose value match the saved value
     });
     if(matches.length){ // if there is any other select with matching value
       failure = true; // set a boolean indicating loop is exited with a match
       return false; // exits the each loop since a match is found, no need of further iteration
     }
  }); 
 }
 if(!failure) // checks whether the loop exited with or without a match
  $("form")[0].submit(); //if there are no matches submit the form manually
});
```

---

Other references:

- [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each) - Iterates over a jquery object
- [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter) - Filters a jquery object by executing a function against each element
- [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not) - Removes matched elements from a jquery object

Side note: you're appending elements with same `id`, which is invalid... remove the `id` attribute from dynamic templates...

Comment: @Starter I updated the ans regarding first query, hope it works. please read my comment below the question and update it with more info... without sample code for reproducing the scenario, we can't test the code..

Comment: @Starter how can i test the second part without sample `HTML` `code..? It is very unlikely that most of the users are running a`PHP` server all the time.. edit the question and update it with the latest code as well as generated `HTML` code instead of `PHP`,

Comment: @T J Thanx dude it works..You saved my time

BTW can you explain the code you have written so that I'll try to grasp it rather than just copying and pasting..

Comment: @Starter I've tried my best to explain it... let me know if i can improve it somehow...

Comment: @T J Perfect explanation dude.. Thanx

Comment: @T J Can u help me with this please?Its an urgent task for my proj.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344777/validate-dynamically-created-text-inputs-in-jquery